# How to rotate an object during a specific time in OpenGL ES for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES for Android I have an object that I want to rotate with gl.glRotate. But I want this rotation to happen during `n` seconds, not immediately. How can I implement this? I want this to happen during `n` seconds so that the user can see the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How quickly is your object rendered on the View. Suppose it takes time t for one update, then the amount by which you should rotate your object will be (t/n)*r, r being the total amount of rotation  you want in n seconds. So in a total of n seconds, the effective rotation will be r.

Answer (score 0):

use System.currentTimeMillis(); to get time passed .

```
    int seconds=5;//rotate in 5 seconds
    long rotatestarted;
    void  StartRotate()
    {
          rotatestarted=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    void Render()
    {
          if(rotatestarted+seconds*1000<System.currentTimeMillis()){
                 DoRotate();
          }
    }
```

Comment: i think it will rotate immediately after 5 second. i want it rotates during 5 second

Comment: Well, then i think i misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL and OpenGL ES do not provide such functionality. All they provide is ways do draw and transform things *now*, without any consideration of time.

What you need is some system, your own or some framework/library/engine that will handle time, and states relative to it.

In this regard SteveL answer is correct, you have to handle this by yourself.